# Алгоритм перевода стознакового числа в восьмеричную систему

Tags: c#, системы-счисления, длинная-арифметика

На вход подается десятичное стознаковое число. На выходе это же число в восьмеричной системе. Помогите придумать алгоритм перевода **стознакового числа** в восьмеричную систему. Видимо придется работать со строкой и ее частями, потому что C# не умеет работать с числами данной длины. Но не понятно как потом все правильно сложить и вывести, чтобы получить верный результат.

Comment: `BigInteger` справляется и с миллионом десятичных знаков.

Comment: Можно и самому алгоритм реализовать, он не сложный: переводим в 2-чную систему, а затем делим с конца полученную строку по 3 символа, эти 3 символа и переводим в 8-ную систему. Например, 20 (в 10ной) = 10100 (в двоичной), три последних символа - это 100 (в двоичной) или 4 (в восьмиричной). Остается 10 (в двоичной) - это 2 в восьмиричной. Итого получили число 24 (в восьмиричной)

Comment: @BOPOH А как вы предлагаете посимвольно переводить в двоичную из десятичной ? 20 в двоичной, 0010100, а 120 в двоичной 1111000, т.е. третий разряд десятичного числа влияет на младшие разряды в двоичной

Comment: @Mike, я это уже удалил ) из двоичной можно же переводить в 8-ричную не смотря на следующие цифры, вот я и поторопился с выводом, перепрыгнув с 10-чной сразу в двоичную

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- разобрать исходную строку в `BigInteger` (добавить Reference на сборку `System.Numerics` и using на неймспейс `System.Numerics`)
- преобразовать этот `BitInteger` в массив байт
- собрать байты по 3 (24 бита, 8 восьмеричных символов) и преобразовать в строку
- склеить полученную строку

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Text;

public static class BigIntegerExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a <see cref="BigInteger"/> to a octal string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="bigint">A <see cref="BigInteger"/>.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="System.String"/> containing an octal
    /// representation of the supplied <see cref="BigInteger"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public static string ToOctalString(this BigInteger bigint)
    {
        var bytes = bigint.ToByteArray();
        var idx = bytes.Length - 1;

        // Create a StringBuilder having appropriate capacity.
        var base8 = new StringBuilder(((bytes.Length / 3) + 1) * 8);

        // Calculate how many bytes are extra when byte array is split
        // into three-byte (24-bit) chunks.
        var extra = bytes.Length % 3;

        // If no bytes are extra, use three bytes for first chunk.
        if (extra == 0)
        {
            extra = 3;
        }

        // Convert first chunk (24-bits) to integer value.
        int int24 = 0;
        for (; extra != 0; extra--)
        {
            int24 <<= 8;
            int24 += bytes[idx--];
        }

        // Convert 24-bit integer to octal without adding leading zeros.
        var octal = Convert.ToString(int24, 8);

        // Ensure leading zero exists if value is positive.
        if (octal[0] != '0' && bigint.Sign == 1)
        {
            base8.Append('0');
        }

        // Append first converted chunk to StringBuilder.
        base8.Append(octal);

        // Convert remaining 24-bit chunks, adding leading zeros.
        for (; idx >= 0; idx -= 3)
        {
            int24 = (bytes[idx] << 16) + (bytes[idx - 1] << 8) + bytes[idx - 2];
            base8.Append(Convert.ToString(int24, 8).PadLeft(8, '0'));
        }

        return base8.ToString();
    }
}

namespace ConsoleApplication47
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BigInteger value = BigInteger.Parse("2");

            Console.WriteLine(value.ToOctalString());
        }
    }
}
```

код взят с [enSO: Convert BigInteger to decimal, hex, binary, octal string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15447131/1988244)

Если не нужно поддерживать отрицательные значения - уберите часть кода, добавляющую leading zero.

Comment: `24 бита, 4 восьмеричных символа` это верно написано? 24 бита - это ведь 24/3=8, 8 восьмеричных символа?

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov да, спасибо, ошибся. исправил.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы)